# Does minus rep sum with future positive rep score in case of new users?

Tags: support, reputation

If there is user with **1** rep, who asks question, and receives 5 downvotes for it (**-10** rep), that user's rep stays at 1, but in the future they provide an answer that is upvoted one time (**+10** rep), will their rep stay at **1** (**-10 + 10 == 0**)? Or will the downvotes when he was at **1** rep be "forgiven" and their actual rep score will be at **11**?

If it doesn't sum, that is not what I would call fair play.

I am asking this as I am upset because some users abandon questions, and I still catch myself trying to help them.

Comment: Well, don't answer crap questions and you don't have to worry about "fair play".

Comment: @HansPassant I will need to do it, but usually crapy questions are quite easy to help so temptetion is big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or the downvotes when he was at 1 rep will be "forgiven" and his actual rep score will be at 11?

The reputation will indeed be 11.

> I am upset because some users abandon questions, and I still catch myself trying to help them.

Life's too short to get upset about things like that. Help them and move on. Don't help people because you want the votes.

Comment: Thanks Oded. I didn't say I want votes. Only to know if my answer helped or not. And it is not even only for me, but for others that will try to find solution searching the SO.

Comment: Fair, but the fact is - some people come to get help and once they got it leave. Assume you did help. And know that others, if they have the same issue may very well find that question and your answer.