# Minus and Plus Reputation Points for new users

Tags: discussion, reputation, downvotes, voting, new-users

> Yes, I know this is an old talking point, but the current questions on meta about this don't cover my specific issue.

## The Scene:

1) A new user has just posted a question. The user has a reputation of 1.

2) Someone downvotes the question. The question is -1. The users reputation is 1.

3) Someone else comes along and upvotes the question, the question score is 0. the users' reputation is 11.

## BUT:

If the user had +1 question vote first, and *then* the -1 was voted on the question, the user would have a reputation of 9.

**Scene 2:**

1) A new user has just posted a question. The user has a reputation of 1.

2) Someone upvotes the question. The question is +1. The users reputation is 11.

3) Someone else comes along and downvotes the question, the question score is 0. the users' reputation is 9.

## Issue:

This seems to be markedly unfair that the order of votes for a new user (or any user with a 1 reputation) matters in that a matter of seconds between votes can change the reputation that user has.

It's not a big thing, but it seems really inconsistent and since when should the reputation be based on vote timing?

Things I've read:

- [Does minus rep sum with future positive rep score in case of new users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326356/does-minus-rep-sum-with-future-positive-rep-score-in-case-of-new-users)
- [Is there any deficit reputation to be paid back?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288629/is-there-any-deficit-reputation-to-be-paid-back)

Comment: Why is this a problem in practice? It's an edge case and people making useful contributions swiftly move off 1 rep and then it's not an issue any more.

Comment: I've been wondering about that same thing :)

Comment: I'm starting to think that we were better off getting rid of the penalty for receiving a downvote, which in turn would void this concern. Might give some extra thought on this.

Comment: @E_net4isvisible Why not just a lower cap? A post at -3 is considered pretty poor and only slightly visible. If there's no reputation penalty, poor content may be less likely to be improved, but a score of -12 is unlikely to ever be improved because it's too unlikely to get out of the hole.

Comment: @Scratte Because many would disagree that a -3 leaves the same signal as a -12.

Comment: @RobertLongson it may be only relevant to a specific set of circumstances, but it's still relevant. Yes, most people move beyond 11 rep but it's a point as to the order of votes effects the score of the votes.

Comment: You did not find [Oded's advice](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326357/366904) to be a compelling answer to your question? *"Life's too short to get upset about things like that."* What about [Martijn's explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288630/366904)? *"We don't kick people when they are down nor do we save the kicks for when they get up again."* Is this a feature request to save the kicks?

Comment: @CodyGray it's not about kicking people, it's about the inconsistency between rep based solely on the time of the vote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To some extent I agree - it is unfair (for slightly different reasons) that order of votes makes difference - one finds question to be low quality and decides to vote, soon pity upvote comes to compensate giving OP +8 points... if first person does nothing at least there is no reward for poor quality question...

Now more specific to the question - since moral concerns are already covered in [Is there any deficit reputation to be paid back?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288629/is-there-any-deficit-reputation-to-be-paid-back/288630#288630) by Martijn Pieters♦:

> "We don't kick people when they are down nor do we save the kicks for when they get up again."

I'll try to cover technical part to my understanding: current code that computes reputation points for all reputation event is very simple - it only looks at all events ordered by time, and current day's reputation for votes and edits, and total reputation.  If event hits either daily limit of min reputation limit it is ignores, otherwise one or both values updated.

Your suggestion keeping more information during calculation or making visible reputation different from actual (in negative case). While it may strictly speaking be more correct it is more complex and more importantly untested compared to current code. I don't see value of making this change - it does not make reputation changes any easier to explain (why I got +3 for one upvote and +5 for another?) nor makes people feel any better about they current reputation count. The only way to handle it fairly is to show negative reputation (which is just bad idea in my opinion).